# Translation Gaps On Comic Conversation : 1

Tags: character-identification, traditional-characters

As always: I appreciate any help provided. Thanks again.

### Background

I am reading Doraemon (or at least I am trying to read it) and sometimes I can't quite see the character while other times I have an issue with context. In this case, I am just not familiar enough to discern the missing characters (?).

Here is what I see so far,

> 真年過 (?) 開
>
> 是定一年今好事(?)(?) (EDIT: I think this is 連)

Can anyone share the character(s) I am missing based on the image below?

Have I missed any other characters in this frame?

BTW - This is from a Doraemon comic book collection that a friend shared with me. Some one explained to me that this character has at times been depicted speaking in Japanese, Taiwanese, Mandarin, and Cantonese. As a result there are nuances throughout the series which are regional. If there are any regional variations in meaning that stand out please share.

[image: Doraemon-1-1]

### UPDATES

1) Changed the title to better reflect the related questions that I have on this topic.

2) Accepted Answers

> 繁体:過年真清閒 
>   简体:过年真清闲
>
> 繁体:今年一定是好事連連 
>   简体:今年一定是好事连连

3) I also learned from these answers/comments how the comic should be read (right to left) top-bottom.

Comment: read from right to left :)

Comment: @ah_hau Yes, I learned this after reading the answer :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is written in traditional so...

FT:`過年真清閒`
JT:`过年真清闲`
ENG: `New year's is very idle/leisurely/quiet`

FT:`今年一定是好事連連`
JT:`今年一定是好事连连`
ENG: `This year will definitely be filled with one good thing after another`

Nothing too regional...

You didn't miss anything else.

Comment: I can see that FT (?) and JT (?) must mean Traditional and Simplified but not sure of their meaning...

Comment: haha yeah I just used to it shorten fanti (繁體/繁体) and jianti (简体)

Answer (score 2):

過年真清閒 = There is so much leisure time during the New Year Festival.

好事連連 = Good things happening one after another = Good fortune.

Comment: Your point on 好事連連 helped me find 好运连连! 

Comment: Isn't it "好運年年" instead of "好運連連"?